# retrieving data in Power Builder

Tags: powerbuilder

i am using PowerBuilder7.0 version.

I am working on inventory project.
i stucked in retrieving the value problem.

designed search button in main window -- code are -

```
//*********************************************************//
//Clicked Event of Search Button on a Window
//*********************************************************//


gs_srcharg.srchok = false

open(w_srchemp)
if gs_srcharg.srchok = false then  // User has pressed Cancel Button
    return  
end if

dw_1.settaborder("item_code", 0)
dw_1.settaborder("grp_cd",0)
dw_1.settaborder("cat_cd",0)
dw_1.settaborder("sgrp_cd",0)

i_newrec = false
cb_new.enabled=false
//messagebox("er",gs_srcharg.id)
dw_1.retrieve(gs_srcharg.id)
dw_1.SetItem(dw_1.getrow(),"item_code", gs_srcharg.id)
dw_1.enabled = true
set_winbutton(4)
cb_search.enabled=false

//dw_1.settaborder("bank_ac123",0) 
/***************************************************************************
end of script
***************************************************************************/

and w_srchemp's code  --
string t_sqlst  
string t_srchempcd

t_srchempcd = sle_empcd.text
t_sqlst = "select item_code from item_mast where item_code = '" + trim(t_srchempcd) + "'"

declare cur_srch dynamic cursor for SQLSA;
prepare SQLSA from :t_sqlst;
open dynamic cur_srch;

fetch cur_srch into :t_srchempcd;

// If document does not exists then
if sqlca.sqlcode <> 0 then
    messagebox("Search Error", "This Item code does not exist")
    close cur_srch;
    open(w_emphlp)
    sle_empcd.text = message.stringparm 
    return
end if

close cur_srch;
close(parent)  //Close seach window

return
/***************************************************************************
End of script
***************************************************************************/
```

after this, whatever we search the code, we get value in main window but value is first row of table every time.
i want exact value, when we search. Please help ..

Comment: So you retrieve data into a datawindow (dw_1 in your example) then have some stuff in a cursor.  Is the cursor searching the result set in the datawindow or for some other purpose?

Comment: yes, retrieve data into a datawindow and after retrieving , want to update the data. if we set the data into dw then we got the error "the table has a unique "..

Comment: This is still unclear. What do you mean by 'set the data into dw'?  Are you using setitem or similar methods to update the values in the dw?  Then you try to update the dw and you get some sort of error?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using cursor here for searching . You can directly call the sql query.

Long ll_item_code

select item_code INTO :ll_item_code
    from item_mast 
    where item_code =long(trim(t_srchempcd))

---

And you are matching the item_code here and you are retrieving the same item code from SQL Query. 
Check your SQL Query.
And if your sql statement gives more output , then you should use loop statements to get the appropriate results. So check for SQL Cursor on internet.

Regards

Raj

Comment: thanks for reply .. one more question please..
on which control we can fetch all the value ??and whats the code??

Comment: And i want to retrieve data .not set the data. if we use this method we can't update the values.

Comment: If you have a result set in a datawindow and wish to search for values within that result set you should use the Find method.

Comment: You can use datawindow to retrieve the values from the database. As well as you can do update on that same datawindow control. For that you need to set update properties for the datawindow. So when you do any modifications with little code you can update the changes to the datawindow. In powerbuilder there is a default help file is located. see that for more help. To retreive the data you should specify the retrieval argument for the datawindow control. So you can pass the argument based on that data will be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use a dynamic datastore? You can create it with:

```
new_syntax = "select item_code from item_mast where...."
dw_new.Create(new_syntax, error_create)
```

Well, now you easily can iterate the new datastore with a for cycle, filter, order...